# Excel nested IF statement not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Having trouble pulling a nested if statement. Trying to say if a date is over under another date it is "Moving" or "Not Moving". Should not be a big deal but can not seem to figure out why they all pull "Moving" even though it is not correct.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(N2,$O$2:$P$5048,2,FALSE)>=$L$4,"Moving",IF(VLOOKUP(N2,$O$2:$P$5048,2,FALSE) < $L$4,"Not Moving", ))
```

https://ibb.co/bvGSgk

https://ibb.co/emovZ5

Also my first-time post. I apologize for any incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the second IF when only two outputs are expected:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(N2,O2:$P$5048,2,FALSE)>=$L$4,"Moving","Not Moving")
```

Simply it is

```
=IF(Condition, What to do if true, What to do if false)
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

---

Also are you sure about the `O2` being relative?  It makes more sense that it should be `$O$2`

In fact, there is no detriment to using full column references in VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(N2,$O:$P,2,FALSE)>=$L$4,"Moving","Not Moving")
```

Comment: Every value is now 'Not Moving". >=IF(VLOOKUP(N2,O:Q,3,FALSE)>=$L$4,"Moving","Not Moving")

Comment: Then the issue is with the data and not the formula.  Without a snapshot of the data we cannot be of more help.

Comment: Added images of the data.

Comment: Try just the vlookup, does it return what you expect, if not get that working first.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but it looks like you are comparing a text (column P) to a number $L$4. either wrap the vlookup with =Value() or convert column P to numbers. Also, I'm not sure the vlookup is really what you want, as you are just comparing values in column p to $L$4. If you are looking for the last entry of that number in column N, then you'll need a different formula.

Comment: My second part about use of vlookup if your data doesn't have duplicates, then you don't need vlookup. If your data has duplicates, then you need to sort (or use different formula) as vlookup will grab the data from the first occurrence of the  item to be looked up. Hope this is understandable.