# Find the position with specific condition in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of student who need to score minimum 40 marks for each subject(five subjects) to get position. For example if a student does not get more than or equal to 40 marks in each subject, he/she will not be ranked and should be skipped from giving position. The following is my current not working solution.

```
=IF(IF(COUNTIF(C2:G2,">=40")=5,TRUE,FALSE), RANK(H2,H$2:H$6),"NA")
```

This does not work correct because, it does not skip the ranking. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `COUNTIF(C2:G2,">=40")=5` I would use the following, for simplicity:

```
IF(min(C2:G2)<40, "FAIL", "PASS")
```

i.e. if the smallest number is less than 40, FAIL, but  if they're all above 40 so the smallest of all the numbers is more than/equal to 40, PASS. In your example you'll replace "PASS" with the rank formula

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two IF() statements if there are only two possible choices.  A [good explanation](https://superuser.com/questions/1244366/excel-nested-if-statement-not-working/1244369#1244369) of this was given recently.

Quoting that answer, the IF() statement is simply:

```
=IF(Condition, What to do if true, What to do if false).
```

You have the condition correct: `COUNTIF(C2:G2,">=40")=5`

... and the what to do if true: `RANK(H2,H$2:H$6)`

... and the what to do if false: `"NA"`

So all you need to do is combine them in one IF() statement.